# Parser for JSON String

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a parser for a JSON String.

A valid example, per my parser, would be: `"\"foobar\""` or `"\"foo\"bar\""`.

Here's what I attempted, but it does not terminate:

```
parseEscapedQuotes :: Parser String
parseEscapedQuotes = Parser f
  where
    f ('"':xs) = Just ("\"", xs)
    f _        = Nothing

parseStringJValue :: Parser JValue
parseStringJValue = (\x -> S (concat x)) <$> 
         ((char '"') *> 
         (zeroOrMore (alt parseEscapedQuotes (oneOrMore (notChar '"')))) 
         <* (char '"'))
```

My reasoning is that, I can have a repetition of either escaped quotes `"\""` or characters not equal to `"`.

But it's not working as I expected:

```
ghci> runParser parseStringJValue "\"foobar\""
Nothing
```

Comment: Provide an SSCCE please.

Comment: What is `(zeroOrMore (alt parseEscapedQuotes (oneOrMore (notChar '"'))))` supposed to do? What is `alt`? Why not just `zeroOrMore (notChar '"')`?

Comment: Because I want to handle escaped quotes, @user2407038.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what parser combinator library you are using, but here is a working example using Parsec. I'm using monadic style to make it clearer what's going on, but it is easily translated to applicative style.

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

jchar :: Parser Char
jchar = escaped <|> anyChar

escaped :: Parser Char
escaped = do
  char '\\'
  c <- oneOf ['"', '\\', 'r', 't' ] -- etc.
  return $ case c of
            'r' -> '\r'
            't' -> '\t'
            _   -> c

jstringLiteral :: Parser String
jstringLiteral = do
  char '"'
  cs <- manyTill jchar (char '"') 
  return cs

test1 = parse jstringLiteral "" "\"This is a test\""
test2 = parse jstringLiteral "" "\"This is an embedded quote: \\\" after quote\""
test3 = parse jstringLiteral "" "\"Embedded return: \\r\""
```

Note the extra level of backslashes needed to represent parser input as Haskell string literals. Reading the input from a file would make creating the parser input more convenient.

The definition of the `manyTill` combinator is:

```
manyTill p end      = scan
  where
    scan  = do{ end; return [] }
            <|>
            do{ x <- p; xs <- scan; return (x:xs) }
```

and this might help you figure out why your definitions aren't working.

Comment: What's the meaning of `char '\\'` in `escaped`? PS - It's a custom parser library that I'm working on.

Comment: also, my initial problem was that `zeroOrMore` has type `Parser a -> Parser [a]`. I was trying to call `<|> (zeroOrMore (notQuote)) escaped`, but it was not working as expected: `runParser parseStringJValue "\"fo\"obar\""`
=== `Just (S "fo","obar\"")`

Comment: The `char` function recognizes a single charater, e.g. `char 'x'` recognizes the character 'x'. The character literal `'\\'` is how you represent the backslash character.

Comment: So an escaped character sequence is a backslash character followed by a double-quote, backslash, the letter 'r' or the letter 't' - and that's what the `escaped` parser recognizes.